# Browser Extension - How to get the current page's URL

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am making a custom button. When I click that,it should show the "current page's URL".
I found the answer as "document.location" or "windows.location" . But, both points to the local XUL location "chrome://browser/content/browser.xul" not the original URL. Can anybody show how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try anyone of these.. One should definitely work,

> window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href;
>
> window.content.location.href

```
function getURL{

    var currentWindow = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");

    var currBrowseSession = currentWindow.getBrowser();
    var currURL = currBrowseSession.currentURI.spec;

    return currURL;
}
```

Comment: The first one window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href;  worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Coool... I guess so.. Since I have used both :)