# Get Current URL

Tags: javascript, browser-addons

I tried to make an add-ons to send the URL of a website that I'm open,

```
function xxxx() 
{
a = "mailto:xxx@xxxx.com?subject= xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + document.title;
a += "&body=" + escape("url" + window.location.href);
window.location.href = a;
}
```

but that appears is

"chrome :/ / browser / content / browser.xul" << overlay in chrome.manifest

is there any solution or any other way to solve that problem?

Comment: This is Chrome-specific. You need to get the URL of the active tab.

Comment: The solution is `window.content.location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.URL
```

Or

```
location.href
```

for more browser support.

[window.location object on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)

Comment: the problem is why the url links that appear is overlay url "chrome :/ / browser / content / browser.xul" at file "chorme.manifest"? not the url that I'm open

Comment: This does not fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

For most browsers:

```
document.URL
```

For some versions if FF:

```
window.location.href
```

Answer (score -1):

use this in jquery

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

OR in Javascript

```
alert(window.location);
```

hope this helps

Comment: the problem is why the url links that appear is overlay url "chrome :/ / browser / content / browser.xul" at file "chorme.manifest"? not the url that I'm open.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some ways of retrieving URL path using Javascript and JQuery

```
//jquery
$(location).attr('href');

//pure javascript
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

For more information, refer this blog post : http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/jquery-current-page-url/

Thank you,

Rahul Patil

Comment: I just got the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555997/browser-extension-how-to-get-the-current-pages-url

Comment: This produces `/content/browser.xul`